# Utilizando case em campo null

Tags: sql, firebird, case, firebird-2.5

Tenho a seguinte estrutura tb_boletim:

```
|Cod|boletim|dt_enviado|
| 1 |  N    | NULL     |
| 2 |  S    |24/08/2018|
| 3 |  S    | NULL     |
| 4 |  S    |23/08/2018|
| 5 |  S    |23/08/2018|
| 6 |  S    | NULL     |
| 7 |  N    | NULL     |
| 8 |  N    | NULL     |
```

Quero fazer SOMENTE um sql que me traga de duas formas, dependendo parâmetro passado para o campo "boletim".

Consigo fazer um case no where tipo assim?

```
select * from tb_boletim where
boletim = 'S' and
case
 when boletim = 'S' then dt_enviado is not null
 when boletim = 'N' then dt_enviado null
end
```

Resultado esperado:

```
|Cod|boletim|dt_enviado|
| 2 |  S    |24/08/2018|
| 4 |  S    |23/08/2018|
| 5 |  S    |23/08/2018|
```

ou

```
|Cod|boletim|dt_enviado|
| 1 |  N    | NULL     |
| 7 |  N    | NULL     |
| 8 |  N    | NULL     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, consegue.
O parâmetro recebido (`@parametro_boletim`) controlará se a validação será feita com ele igual a `S` ou a `N`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_boletim 
WHERE boletim = @parametro_boletim
  ((boletim = 'S' and dt_enviado is not null) OR
   (boletim = 'N' and dt_enviado null))
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se percebi completamente a questão…

Será isto que pretende?

---

```
select 
   Cod
  ,boletim
  ,case when boletim='S' then dt_enviado else NULL END dt_enviado 
FROM tb_boletim
```

---

```
/*WHERE BOLETIM='S'*/
/*WHERE BOLETIM='N'*/
```

---

Pode acrescentar uma clausula WHERE para filtrar ou não de acordo com o campo BOLETIM